# Export string with single backslashes in Python

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to create command to send to a Microsoft SQL Server that includes a file path, but I can't figure out how to send a string that has single backslashes in it.

I'm creating the string like this:

`>>> bulk_insert_string = r"BULK INSERT my_table FROM {} WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ';', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')".format(
    os.path.join('C:', os.sep, 'data_import_folder', 'my_import_filename' + '.txt'))`

Then if I print that string, it looks like I need it:

```
>>> print(bulk_insert_string)
BULK INSERT my_table FROM C:\data_import_folder\my_import_filename.txt WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ';', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

But when I execute the command using SQLAlchemy, I get this error back:

```
>>>  engine.execute(bulk_insert_string)
```

`ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'C:'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)") [SQL: "BULK INSERT my_table FROM C:\\data_import_folder\\my_import_filename.txt WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ';', ROWTERMINATOR = '\\n')"]`

Comment: I'm not convinced it's the backslashes.  Try putting quotes around the filename?

Comment: @CAB That was it!  Aghhh, I kept seeing the double backslashes in that exception and I missed that I wasn't quoting the filename.  Thanks for your help!